# Как доработать регулярное выражение?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

нуждаюсь в небольшой помощи с регулярками. У меня есть регулярное выражение, которое осталось доделать, а сам не справлюсь. Регулярка должна "отмечать" все комментарии, кроме тех, что являются строками. Проблемы следующие:

1.//-Комменты не удаляются, хотя по ссылке https://regex101.com/r/6ZpIiv/1 видно что регулярка работает

2.Если удаляет, то удаляет везде. Можно ли как-то исключить удаления из строк (СТРОКА 10 НА ПЕРВОМ ФОТО)?

3.Так же нужно учесть одинарные кавычки и не удалять их содержимое, по типу `'//hello'`

Вот код: JS:

```
//Главная функция 
function commentsStrip(object){
    //проверка на поддержку браузером FILE API
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.Blob) {
        var content = ''; //переменная для записи содержимого файла
        var file = object.files[0]; // первый элемент массива файлов
        var reader = new FileReader();
        //при успешном прогружении файла записать содержимое в переменную
        reader.onload = function(){
            content = reader.result;
            //удалить комментарии
            let a = content.replace(/(?:(?:\/\*[\W\w]*?\*\/\n?)|(?:\/\/.*(?=\n)))/gm, '');
            //Вернуть функцию для скачивания готового документа
            return(download(a, file.name, file.type));
        }
        //считать как простой текст
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }else{
        alert("Нужные File API не поддерживаются вашим браузером!");
    }
}
```

Результат работы можно видеть на фото: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не забудьте про строки в одинарных кавычках и шаблоны строк... `'//hello'` и не знаю как в комменте добавить код шаблона строки...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Спасибо. Хотел бы узнать, как у более опытного товарища: какими еще методами можно выполнить поставленную задачу (удаление комментариев из выбранного файла)?

Comment: я как то делал такое регулярками, но у меня не было задачи охватить то, что делаете Вы, я работал с конкретными исходниками из которых удалял только блочные комментарии и определенные проверки, я думаю в целом Вы на верном пути

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Большое вам спасибо)

Comment: В данном случае, как и в случае с разбором html лучше применить специальные инструменты для разбора текста.

Comment: @Grundy например gulp-decomment || gulp-strip-comments??

Comment: @Glechik, я не знаю что это за пакеты. Плюс не совсем понятно в какой среде ты это хочешь делать: browser, nodejs, в текстовом редакторе каком-то? Чем отличается данный вопрос, от двух твоих предыдущих?

Comment: @Glechik если уж на то пошло и решил пилить велосипед, то почему бы просто не взять эти самые `gulp-decomment` и прочие и просто не посмотреть в их исходник?

Comment: @СергейМишин простите, не смог найти нужного варианта. Может вы мне поможете?

Comment: Так я и говорю - посмотрите в исходник плагина и возьмите их решение допилив

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покопавшись на форумах нашел, все-таки, нужную регулярку

```
var RE_BLOCKS = new RegExp([
      /\/(\*)[^*]*\*+(?:[^*\/][^*]*\*+)*\//.source,           // $1: многострочный коммент
      /\/(\/)[^\n]*$/.source,                                 // $2 однострочный коммент
      /"(?:[^"\\]*|\\[\S\s])*"|'(?:[^'\\]*|\\[\S\s])*'|`(?:[^`\\]*|\\[\S\s])*`/.source,
      /(?:[$\w\)\]]|\+\+|--)\s*\/(?![*\/])/.source,           // - оператор деления
      /\/(?=[^*\/])[^[/\\]*(?:(?:\[(?:\\.|[^\]\\]*)*\]|\\.)[^[/\\]*)*?\/[gim]*/.source
      ].join('|'),                                            // - РЕГУЛЯРКА
      'gm'  
    );
```

Comment: приведи пример как ты ее использовал, возможно она заменяет даже то, что похоже на комментарий внутри строки

Comment: [Вот мой гитхаб](https://github.com/Georgin01/Comment-strip) тут все описано

Comment: 1. Всё необходимое должно быть в ответе. 2. Не работает: `var x = /\/* */;` превращается в `var x = `.